# How to select records with unnest columns doesnt have key

Tags: google-bigquery

i have a bq table i record product information. each row has a nested column called `categories` and each product might have more than one category. how can i select products that are not in the category i specified

i tried following code but  i still get all the product in the table, i think because each products have other categories than 'Unwanted Category'. how should i rewrite my select ?

```
SELECT * FROM xx.products, 
unnest(categories) as categories 
WHERE 
categories.name not in ('Unwanted Category')
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.products` AS (
  SELECT 1 product_id, ['Unwanted Category', 'category A'] categories UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ['category A', 'category B'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, ['category C']
)
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.products`
WHERE NOT 'Unwanted Category' IN UNNEST(categories)
```

with result

```
Row product_id  categories   
1   2           category A   
                category B   
2   3           category C
```

I just realized, you might have slightly different schema, thus modified approach - as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.products` AS (
  SELECT 1 product_id, [STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>(1, 'Unwanted Category'), (2, 'category A')] categories UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>(2, 'category A'), (3, 'category B')] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, [STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>(4, 'category C')]
)
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.products`
WHERE NOT 'Unwanted Category' IN (SELECT name FROM UNNEST(categories))
```

with output

```
Row product_id  categories.id   categories.name  
1   2           2               category A   
                3               category B   
2   3           4               category C
```

Comment: its probably my stupidity but i couldn't get this to work with my data. gonna have some sleep and try again. thank you very much by the way :))

Comment: good luck. hopefully you will make it work for your data. you have not provided any example of it  - but I thought I was quite close to what I think you have :o)